# What is the difference between "rico" and "bueno" when referring to taste?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, adjetivos, comida

My Spanish textbook it has the following examples:

> (estar) bueno - tasty
>
> (estar) rico - tasty

What’s the difference between the two? Is it like the difference between `tasty` and `delicious` (i.e. there isn’t one)?

Or is it more like the difference between ‘tasty’ and ‘yummy’ (i.e. one is a little more informal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 99% with [user13560's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18209/1674): in almost all cases you would use rico and bueno interchangeably.

However, to me living in Spain, there might be subtle differences:

- If you talk about how food looks, you will never use *rico*, but *bueno*:

  > Qué buena pinta tiene esta comida
- To some extent, *rico* has a plus on quality and can be a bit higher while ranking food.
- Finally, *rico* is less common, specially on kids: *bueno* is an adjective that all would use, but *rico* comes later while growing.

Comment: My two-year old kid is learning the basics of the language. In order not to confuse him with words, he tell him about _niños buenos_, but also about _comida rica_. If we say that the food is _buena_ he may think that the food is not behaving good. He has plenty of time to get used to words that have several meanings.

Answer (score 2):

[**Bueno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6EawoZ6) is defined as

> 3. adj. Gustoso, apetecible, agradable, divertido.

while [**Rico**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WSXT9Bo) is

> 5. adj. Gustoso, sabroso, agradable.

So in this sense they are synonyms.